# MVC3 Sample Project Database Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I am running Visual Studio 2010 and I created the default MVC3 sample project. The project starts fine and I get the home page.

But when I go to register a new user I get this error,

```
    An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 5177 and the SqlException message is: An unexpected error occurred while checking the sector size for file 'D:\WORK\VISUAL STUDIO PROJECTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\MVC3\MVC3\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF'. Move the file to a local NTFS volume, where the sector size can be retrieved. Check the SQL Server error log for more information.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
Creating the ASPNETDB_af8cb88b53744229b5d3dca30395b572 database...
```

I also have SQLServer 2008 R2 installed.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It is trying to create a database 'D:\WORK\VISUAL STUDIO PROJECTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\MVC3\MVC3\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF' and failing to create it.  Firstly check if the file already exists and manually delete it if so.  For me, it was because I was creating a drive using the Windows command:-

subst x: "e:\My Work"

And my solution was on X:, which for some reason the app did not like.  You can also try creating the database 'D:\WORK\VISUAL STUDIO PROJECTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\MVC3\MVC3\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF' manually in Visual Studio and see if you get the same error.
If you can't create it, look at the drive/folder settings such as make sure it is NTFS drive and check rights etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by the disk mapping, I have mapped a folder C:\abc as a virtual disk, then the error occurred while I run app from the virtual disk, move the projects outside of the virtual disk solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to have express edition installed, generally to run the programs which we download from online. or else if  you have developer edition or enterprise edition of SQL installed you  need to change the connection string in web.config to you database  and before that don't forget to copy database form APPData folder to you database.

Hope this should work.